# Text tag '@<text>' does not work when used as an argument

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc

When I do something similar to the following example, it results in the `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type` error. I'm not sure if that is a normal behavior or there's something wrong with how I use it.

```
@(Html.Kendo.Dialog().Content(@<text> Some Html Code </text>))
```

However, what do I have to do if I wanna pass something like that, let's say a long html code containing scripts, etc., to a helper function?

Comment: Shouldn't you just be writing `@(Html.Kendo.Dialog().Content("Some Html Code")`?

Comment: @DavidG: It will be really really inconvenient to write html code that way. I hope you get my point.

Comment: Indeed, but code like this is compiled as plain C# so that's how it has to be